# How to integrate extJs with zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, extjs

Can anyone tell me how to integrate extJs with zend framework. I have googled a lot and there is not much info about this.

Comment: What do mean by integrating? How-to include JS files and use ExtJS functions in a ZF project? Or do you mean with something like ZendX_JQuery? Could you be more specific what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes something like ZendX_JQuery

Answer (score 0):

I, myself wouldn't use something like that and itergrate it myself to retain flexabillity. It looks like there isn't a Zendx implementation but you could have a look at these:

http://zefext.sourceforge.net/
http://aboutfrontend.com/extjs/extdesigner-extjs-and-zend-framework/
http://www.slideshare.net/ThorstenSuckow/zend-framework-mvc-driven-extjs

Hope this helps you a bit!